# event binding in MVVM

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, binding

my code in ViewModel :

```
public void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Insert_Click");
}
```

code in View :

```
<Button Click="{Binding Insert_Click}"  Background="Black" Height="56" Name="btnAdd" Width="57">
</Button>
```

error :

> Error 1   Click="{Binding Insert_Click}" is not valid. '{Binding
>   Insert_Click}' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance
>   methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid

Please show me the correct code

Comment: My answer does not really address MVVM, just your error message. aqwert's answer is a better long term solution, but will require a bit of reading up on commanding. (edit: I deleted my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event hook ups will only work for code behind to the control/window if you remove the `Binding` syntax from the event handler. For MVVM it is a bit different. You can get that to work if you move the handler to the code behind but I suspect you want to use MVVM.

Here what you really need is to use the Command pattern

```
<Button Command="{Binding Insert}" Background="Black" Height="56" Name="btnAdd" Width="57"/>
```

and view model

```
public ViewModel()
{
     Insert = new RelayCommand(Insert_Click);
}

public ICommand Insert { get; private set; }


private void Insert_Click()
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Insert_Click");
}
```

This is using a framework such as [MVVM light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1.  This classic post explains commanding very well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx.  You don't need a framework (MVVM Light) to do this, as the RelayCommand from the article by itself will work.  (Not to say you *shouldn't* use MVVM Light!).

Comment: Just mentioned MVVMLight as a framework so RelayCommand didn't become a mystery. You of course can roll your own, in the early days that is what I did but frameworks now are all quite well developed. Thanks for the link